# EF 7 query GroupBy + EF.Property() property not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some complicated logic with EF query, but if I simplify it (and change names) then it will looks like this:

```
var queryable = _dbContext.Journal.GroupBy(x => x.TicketId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.BeginDate).First());

queryable = queryable.Where(p => EF.Property<bool>(p, "IsDeleted") == false);

await queryable.ToListAsync()
```

It throws an exception

> Translation of `'EF.Property<bool>(ProjectionBindingExpression: 0, "IsDeleted")'` failed. Either the query source is not an entity type, or the specified property does not exist on the entity type

But of course `IsDeleted` exists both in model and in the database. More than that, it works if I do not use `GroupBy`.

Why does `GroupBy` make `IsDeleted` unavailable?

Comment: _"but of course `IsDeleted` exists both in model"_ - if it exists in the model why you can't use it directly in the where clause?

Comment: Why can't you filter before the grouping?

Comment: @RicardoPeres because there is actually some generic logic, which contains also Skip().Take() filters, i've simplified code here. Anyway i'm just trying to figure out why it doesn't work

Comment: @GertArnold no, why? the `Select()` returns IQueryable<Journal>, because there is `First()` inside

Comment: @GuruStron because some complicated logic, so simple answer - i just can't for whatever reason.

Comment: @RicardoPeres because it will be different query? Current one should return all groups which have the latest (by `BeginDate`) which is not deleted while if you will filter first then you will get all groups which have at least one non-deleted entry.

Comment: TBH I was not able to repro, I get _"Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary."_ which seems to be a EF Core bug based on github issues.

Comment: btw `OrderByDescending` doesn't matter here, exception is the same even without it, just with `GroupBy(x => x.TicketId).Select(x => x.First())`

Comment: @GuruStron just tested with EF 8, nothing changed

Comment: @SUDALV 1) I got the exception I wrote about on both EF 7 and 8 2) The issues I have mentioned were not closed.

Comment: @GuruStron okay i got the same exception as you, the difference is my query also has some `.Include()` which i not mentioned. All `Include` are in the beginning of query. So without `Include` i have the same exception as you.

Comment: `queryable.ToQueryString()` before the `EF.Property` filter give me SQL like this (names changed)
https://pastebin.com/S9KqPVsh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257151/discussion-between-sudalv-and-guru-stron).

Comment: Yes, I missed the `First`. But that means that, in this case, you should be able to do `Where(p => p.IsDeleted) == false`, just for diagnostic purposes. If so, then it's clear that this is a bug.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, it throws similar exception with `p.IsDeleted`

Comment: Then you really should supply a [mre]. There's no way we can reproduce this based on the code you supplied.